# How to identify the available computational devices with metal in iphone or mac

Tags: ios, macos, gpu, metal

Could anyone present an example to illustrate how to identify the available computational devices, such as cpu and gpu, with metal? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Metal` only works on GPUs. That said, there is a function named `MTLCopyAllDevices()` that returns all the GPUs your system has. Here is a quick example on how I run this in a OS X playground to see what compatible devices my system has.

[image]

EDIT:

In `Objective-C` this would look similar. Just import `<Metal/Metal.h>` first:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSArray *devices = MTLCopyAllDevices();
    for (id device in devices) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [device name]);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks @Marius. However, could it be implemented with object-c. I am a newcomer of Metal.

Comment: I have google MLTCopyAllDevices, but I got no valueable results.

Comment: The documentation is here: [`MTLCopyAllDevices`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLFunctions_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/MTLCopyAllDevices). This function is only available on OS X. On iOS, there is only one device, and you get it by calling [`MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLFunctions_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice).